# Which part of the Covid relief bill mandates to publish a UFO report?

Tags: united-states

It was reported that the [Consolidated Appropriations Act, 2021](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consolidated_Appropriations_Act,_2021) ([H.R.133](https://www.congress.gov/bill/116th-congress/house-bill/133)) ($2.3 trillion coronavirus relief and government funding bill) signed on December 27, 2020 contains a provision which mandates the US intelligence agencies to publish a report about unidentified flying objects (UFOs). For example [here](https://www.vice.com/en/article/93wnky/emergency-covid-stimulus-will-likely-reveal-ufo-documents).

Exactly which part of [its text](https://www.congress.gov/bill/116th-congress/house-bill/133/text) says so?

Comment: This seems perfectly clear. What details does anyone think are needed?

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the Consolidated Appropriations Act of 2021 (HR 133) included several bills that had already been voted out of committee and were waiting for full congressional approval, including the [Intelligence Authorization Act for Fiscal Year 2021](https://www.intelligence.senate.gov/publications/intelligence-authorization-act-fiscal-year-2021) (referred to as "Division W" within HR 133.)  This authorization act includes the following text:

> ### Advanced Aerial Threats
>
> The Committee supports the efforts of the Unidentified
> Aerial Phenomenon Task Force at the Office of Naval
> Intelligence to standardize collection and reporting on
> unidentified aerial phenomenon, any links they have to
> adversarial foreign governments, and the threat they pose to
> U.S. military assets and installations. However, the Committee
> remains concerned that there is no unified, comprehensive
> process within the Federal Government for collecting and
> analyzing intelligence on unidentified aerial phenomena,
> despite the potential threat. The Committee understands that
> the relevant intelligence may be sensitive; nevertheless, the
> Committee finds that the information sharing and coordination
> across the Intelligence Community has been inconsistent, and
> this issue has lacked attention from senior leaders.
>
> Therefore, the Committee directs the DNI, in consultation
> with the Secretary of Defense and the heads of such other
> agencies as the Director and Secretary jointly consider
> relevant, to submit a report within 180 days of the date of
> enactment of the Act, to the congressional intelligence and
> armed services committees on unidentified aerial phenomena
> (also known as "anomalous aerial vehicles"), including
> observed airborne objects that have not been identified.
>
> The Committee further directs the report to include:
>
> 1. A detailed analysis of unidentified aerial
>    phenomena data and intelligence reporting collected or
>    held by the Office of Naval Intelligence, including
>    data and intelligence reporting held by the
>    Unidentified Aerial Phenomena Task Force;
> 2. A detailed analysis of unidentified phenomena data
>    collected by:
>    a. geospatial intelligence;
>    b. signals intelligence;
>    c. human intelligence; and
>    d. measurement and signals intelligence;
> 3. A detailed analysis of data of the FBI, which was
>    derived from investigations of intrusions of
>    unidentified aerial phenomena data over restricted
>    United States airspace;
> 4. A detailed description of an interagency process
>    for ensuring timely data collection and centralized
>    analysis of all unidentified aerial phenomena reporting
>    for the Federal Government, regardless of which service
>    or agency acquired the information;
> 5. Identification of an official accountable for the
>    process described in paragraph 4;
> 6. Identification of potential aerospace or other
>    threats posed by the unidentified aerial phenomena to
>    national security, and an assessment of whether this
>    unidentified aerial phenomena activity may be
>    attributed to one or more foreign adversaries;
> 7. Identification of any incidents or patterns that
>    indicate a potential adversary may have achieved
>    breakthrough aerospace capabilities that could put
>    United States strategic or conventional forces at risk;
>    and
> 8. Recommendations regarding increased collection of
>    data, enhanced research and development, and additional
>    funding and other resources.
>    The report shall be submitted in unclassified form, but may
>    include a classified annex.